# image with text in typehead autocomplete in AngularUI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

is it possible to insert image also in the autocomplete dropdown in the typehead of angular JS UI

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a [template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) to accomplish this.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
   <a>
      <img ng-src="{{match.model.img}}" width="16"> {{match.model.name}}
   </a>
</script>
```

The data bound to the typeahead is as follows:

```
$scope.results = [
  {
    name: "California",
    img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flag_of_California.svg/45px-Flag_of_California.svg.png"
  }, {
    name: "Delaware",
    img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c6/Flag_of_Delaware.svg/45px-Flag_of_Delaware.svg.png"
  }, {
    name: "Florida",
    img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg/45px-Flag_of_Florida.svg.png"
  }
];
```

Each result is a JSON object made up of a `name` and an image URL (`img`).

The HTML template displays the image using the `img` attribute of the matching result(s). To tell the typeahead to use the template you can use the `typeahead-template-url`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" class="form-control" typeahead="name as result.name for result in results | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" />
```

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdxvL1wd/2/) for a working example.